# Loop returning svalue from combobox

Tags: r, gwidgets

This is my first post here but I am a regular stackoverflow visitor.

For uploading new datasets, I am processing a dataframe in which one column has some typing mistake. I want users to modify the error from a gcombobox, thus the errors and the correct value will be stored and automatically corrected the next time.

```
# Sample data which includes a wrong countryid
Incorrect_Country = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), countryid=c("Canadada", "Peruru", "Chinanan"), othercolumn=c("777", "111", "333"))

# Dataframe where some previous pitfalls have been stored 
#(it´s useful because the model can learn from previous pitfalls)
Country_Recode = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), Remote.Name=c("Frankekz", "Potuugal", "Mexxico"), Name=c("France", "Portugal", "Mexico"))

# This table presents values for the combobox
Master_Country = data.frame(name=c("Canada", "Peru", "China", "France", "Portugal", "Mexico"))
```

This is the code: ( GUI toolkit  :gWidgetstcltk)

```
# Define errors in country
Rewrite_Country = unique(sqldf("SELECT * FROM Incorrect_Country WHERE countryid NOT IN  (SELECT 'Remote.Name' FROM Country_Recode)"))

B <- 0

# Dataframe where to store the wrong names which the respective correction
error <- data.frame(x=integer(0), y= character(0), z = character(0))

# Loop for each row with typing errors
for (i in Rewrite_Country["countryid"])  {
    B <- B + 1

    # I create a dialog for preventing several windows to pop up 
    # as this produced that the returned value from a combobox was assigned to the wrong recode name 
    gconfirm("New Value not specified. Do u want to change it?", handler=function(h,...){

        # I create the window which will include a combobox of correct values    
        w <- gwindow("Recode Country for:")
        gp <- ggroup(container=w)

        ## A group for the message and buttons
        i.gp <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container = gp)
        glabel(i, container=i.gp)

        ## Combobox including the correct names
        cb <- gcombobox(Master_Country[["name"]], selected=0, container=i.gp)
        addHandlerChanged(cb,handler=function(h,...)  {

            # I assign the combobox's svalue to a new global variable
            aNew <- as.character()
            assign("aNew", svalue(cb), envir = as.environment(1)) 
            print(svalue(cb))

            })

        ## A group to organize the buttons
        button.group <- ggroup(container = i.gp)
        ## Push buttons to right
        addSpring(button.group) 

        # Ok Button for storing the resuts: (index, wrong value, correct value)     
        button <- gbutton("ok", handler = function(h,...) {
            error <- rbind(error, c(B,i, aNew))

            # In one of the last tries I set the new environment for the table 
            assign("error", error, envir = as.environment(1)) 
            print(error)
            dispose(w) 
        }, container = button.group)

        gbutton("cancel", handler = function(h,...) dispose(w), container=button.group)            
    }) 

}
```

I don't get my expected outcome. I find very hard to retrieve the svalue from the combobox and impossible to store several results from the variable "aNew" when running the loop. Also happens these other two incidents:

1 - when I run the code including the loop: It does not "use to!" enter the widgets (confirm popup)

2 - The loop exists after disposing the first "Recode Country" window, so to say, processing "canadada"

What I really want is that the user can fix the errors in the data.frame Incorrect_Country. Then the error and the solution are stored (data frame: error) for the program to know how to deal with it for future uploads.
How it should work:

1- confirm window (for stopping the loop till the user has corrected the previous error)
2- pop up shows error "canadada"
3- user selects from combobox "canada"
4- Pressing ok will store an integer, the error, and the corrected name in the table   error
5- The loop runs again (press confirm and shows "Peruru")
6- Finally I get the error table such as

```
    x, y, z  
    1, canadada, Canada    
    2, Perurur, Peru  
    3, chinanan, China
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please check out the FAQ on posting -- we need a reproducible sample of your data, the error messages you're getting, and what your expected results are, for starters.

Comment: Sorry, I hope this version is good enough

Comment: Try using gbasicdialog instead of gwindow